# Working of these two pieces of code

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Here are two pieces of **C** code, but I don't understand how they work:

Program 1 :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define s 10
fun() {
 #undef s
 #define s 20
}
int main(){
 printf("%d\n",s);
 fun();
 printf("%d\n",s);
 return 0;
}
```

```
Output: 20
        20
```

Program 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define s 10
int main(){
 printf("%d\n",s);
 fun();
 printf("%d\n",s);
 return 0;
}
fun() {
 #undef s
 #define s 20
}
```

```
output: 10
        10
```

What I know is preprocessor works before starting of `main()` and replaces all of its variables.
Here `fun()` is called after one `printf()`, so how are both program are outputting different values by changing the position of `fun()`?

Comment: This question has an exact duplicate here somewhere (I know because I answered it).  The short answer is that preprocessor directives don't obey function scope.

Comment: @CarlNorum Sorry if this post is duplicate, Someone asked me the ouput of second program two days before, I try to figure out the answer and suddenly when I change the position of fun(), result was totally different so, and thanks for reply

Comment: If you ever want to find out what _actually_ gets compiled after the preprocessor runs, just use `gcc -E`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macro will be replaced in compile time itself. so code will be like this after preprocessing,

Case 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>

fun() {
}
int main(){
 printf("%d\n", 20);//latest definition of s will be considered.
 fun();
 printf("%d\n",20);
 return 0;
}
```

Case 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
 printf("%d\n",10); //replaced with 10 only, because in this instance, there is no change in s 
 fun();
 printf("%d\n",10);
 return 0;
}
fun() {
 //#undef s
 //#define s 20 //no use in ur code. 
}

fun_extra() { //Added for demo
   printf("%d\n",s);//will be replaced by 20. 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor doesn't care about scope.  It just goes through the file line by line, in order from top to bottom, and makes textual replacements.  If something is `#define`d or `#undef`ined, it takes effect from that line until the bottom of the file (or another preprocessor statement overrides it).

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessor statements are not executable.  They are... well, preprocessed.  This means that the compiler will perform an initial, single pass and resolve all preprocessing definitions.  If a preprocessing definition is located inside a C control structure, it will be executed regardless of the meaning of the C control structure.  In other words, from the point of view of the preprocessor there is no C code.  Just text (and other preprocessor statements).

In your case, in this first pass:

```
#include<stdio.h>     // File stdio.h is included/copied
#define s 10          // Preprocessor symbol s is defined as 10
fun() {               // Copied literally
    #undef s          // Preprocessor symbol s is undefined
    #define s 20      // Preprocessor symbol s is defined as 20
}                     // Copied literally
int main(){           // Copied literally
   printf("%d\n",s);  // Copied with s substituted, ie. printf("%d\n",20);
   fun();             // Copied literally
   printf("%d\n",s);  // Copied with s substituted, ie. printf("%d\n",20);
   return 0;          // Copied literally
}                     // Copied literally
```

So, the input that really gets compiled is:

```
// Empty line originally corresponding to #include
// Empty line originally corresponding to #define
fun() {
    // Empty line originally corresponding to #undef
    // Empty line originally corresponding to #define
}
int main(){
   printf("%d\n",20);
   fun();
   printf("%d\n",20);
   return 0;
}
```

In particular, note that the `fun` function does not contain *any* C instruction.  Before pre-processing it did contain 2 pre-processing instructions, but:

- They disappeared after pro-processing
- They never really belonged to a function `fun` because at that point there was no function `fun` or any other C code.  Just text and preprocessor statements.

This work is usually done silently and internally by C compilers.  However, many of them have options to save the pre-processed source files.  You should obtain a result like the above (except that `#include<stdio.h>` would expand into many blank lines, and some C code, which here I sinthesized as a single empty line).

The second case is left as an exercise to the OP.